# Remainder of Stirling formula divergent?

Tags: calculus

I was wondering how the remainder of the Stirling formula behaves
for $ n \rightarrow  \infty $, while $n$ is the index of the Bernoulli number.

I got a problem either way: if it diverges then how can Wolfram Alpha
print something like:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsSeries.html      at $(7)$.

It seems as they wrote for $ n \rightarrow  \infty $ but then where is the remainder term?
If it doesn't diverge, the Stirling series in $(7)$ would have to be convergent which isn't true. I was wondering in general how one gets from the Euler-Maclaurin
formula to the Stirling formula as in $(7)$ the only way I see is when the remainder becomes zero for $ n \rightarrow  \infty $.

Can you tell me how the remainder term actually behaves for $ n \rightarrow  \infty $?

Answer (score 2):

All the series at that wolfram page derive from the first one there, which is identified as an *asymptotic* series for the Gamma function. Do you know what an asymptotic series is? If not, there's a link on that page that will help you. Basically, asymptotic series don't converge, but the error is less than the first omitted term.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.2298/AADM130124002N) paper. It contains explicit formulas and error bounds for the remainder term.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Gerry the Stirling is only asymptotic but observe that convergent versions of Stirling formula exist as proposed by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#A_convergent_version_of_Stirling.27s_formula).