# Factorial of a large number and Stirling approximation

Tags: asymptotics, factorial

I'm trying to approximate the factorial of a large number with large precision. I know one can use the the Stirling approximation to do that with the formula:
$$\sqrt{2\pi x} \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x$$

and I also know that there is a better approximation using:
$$\sqrt{2\pi x} \left(\frac x e \right)^x \left(1+\frac{1}{12x}+\frac{1}{288x^2}-\frac{139}{51840x^3}-\frac{571}{2488320x^4}+\cdots \right)$$

but how are those coefficients in $\left(1+\frac{1}{12x}+\frac{1}{288x^2}-\frac{139}{51840x^3}-\frac{571}{2488320x^4}+\cdots\right)$ chosen?

Comment: The coefficients involve the Bernoulli numbers. The main way to obtain that result is from estimating the error in $\ln(n!)-n\ln n\approx \int_1^n\ln x\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation . They come from the Euler–Maclaurin formula and the exponential formula.

Comment: You want to be careful with using too many terms, because the Stirling formula is a non-convergent asymptotic series. Specifically, for each $x$ there is partial sum that is better than any other partial sum, and (for $x$ fixed) as you include more and more terms beyond this optimal truncation of the series, the partial sums then become worse and worse approximations. However, as $x$ gets larger and larger, the optimal truncations of the series include more and more terms (and are relatively more and more accurate), so for really big numbers you can get extremely good approximations.

Comment: @Dave The series given above is diverging ?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, the Stirling series diverges (in the usual sense of convergence and divergence). See [remainder of stirling formula divergent?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136829/remainder-of-stirling-formula-divergent), and [here](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/40asymptotic/), and [also here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-when-we-say-that-an-asymptotic-expansion-is-divergent), and [the first few pages here](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~rajeev/phy493/AsymptoticMethods.pdf).

Comment: See [§5.11(i)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.i) in the DLMF.