# Functions that get closer but don't have a difference converging to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $N$ is the set of all positive integers. Then $$f(x):=\max(\frac{x^{(N-1)}}{\Gamma(N)})\approx \frac{x^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}:=g(x)$$
Unfortunately $f(x)-g(x)$ doesn't converge to $0$ for all values of $x$. Seen [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jqmenvn5jm), the difference between the two diverges to infinity for non-integer values that are arbitrarily large.

But if you look from a different perspective, they converge to each other. Take each point in $f(x)$, and find the distance to the closest point in $g(x)$, then they're very close to each other. If we do this for any point we can find a function for this by finding the global minimum of $Z(x)$ in

$$Z(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(f(x_1)-g(x_2))^2}$$$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_2}=0$$$$ \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_2}=0$$$$\frac{x_2-x_1+f'(x_1)\big(g(x_2)-f(x_1)\big)+x_1-x_2+g'(x_2)\big(f(x_1)-g(x_2)\big)}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(f(x_1)-g(x_2))^2}}=0$$$$ \frac{f'(x_1)\big(g(x_2)-f(x_1)\big)+g'(x_2)\big(f(x_1)-g(x_2)\big)}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(f(x_1)-g(x_2))^2}}=0$$After here, I'm stuck on what to do. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

What's your actual goal? What do you want to do with these functions? What do you need to get out of some notion of closeness?

Comment: Some point on h(x) is evaluated by being the distance between f(x) at that x-value and the closest point on g(x).  I want to find a general solution for h(x).

Comment: For instance if f(x)-1=g(x)=x, h(x)=sqrt(2)/2

Comment: I'm literally rushing out the door right now so right now I can't try to figure out what you're doing, but I *think* what you might be dealing with is something I discussed in the comments to the question [Factorial of a large number and Stirling approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451141/factorial-of-a-large-number-and-stirling-approximation).